# Sorting and Merging data from three different tables in an efficient way

Tags: php, mysql

Consider the following three tables:

```
t1(id,name,cDate,foo,…)
t2(id,name,cDate,bar,…)
t3(id,name,cDate,other,…)
```

The tables represent some independent entities. I need to display them on site homepage regardless of their type in a list sorted by creation date (cDate).

```
rows
---
t1
t2
t2
t3
t2
t1
```

Currently I have created a view (or a subquery) by union of some shared columns and an auxilary column for table name: `v1(id,cDate,tableName)` to select them ordered by cDAte. After that I query on the each table to get tables' rows and merge the result in a PHP array and send back them to view. However I think it is not so efficient and clean. Is there any better approach?

**The output be a ready-to-use resourse containing all data of the three tables.**

Comment: Consider a join query to make things simpler and quicker. Would you be able to join the three tables in one query and then simple add "LIMIT $x,$y", with $y being how many results per page and $x being current page times $y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a improvement of the @John Green answers I created a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16c34/1/0) with the usage of the COALESCE function, it return the first not null argument:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id, t3.id) id
, COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name, t3.name) name
, COALESCE(t1.cDate, t2.cDate, t3.cDate) cDate
, COALESCE(t1.foo, t2.bar, t3.other) uniqueField
FROM (
    SELECT 't1' AS source, id FROM t1
    UNION
    SELECT 't2' AS source, id FROM t2
    UNION
    SELECT 't3' AS source, id FROM t3
) ad
LEFT JOIN t1 ON ad.id = t1.id AND ad.source = 't1'
LEFT JOIN t2 ON ad.id = t2.id AND ad.source = 't2'
LEFT JOIN t3 ON ad.id = t3.id AND ad.source = 't3'
ORDER BY cDate
```

The advantage of using this method is that you can combine the fields that are not common in all the tables the way your business rules require, as shown in the `uniqueField`

Comment: Thanks for `COALESCE` function.

Comment: The indexes will disappear with this approach right? So if you have a PK id. The sorting will take too much time or if you have a unique index on 1 text column searching or sorting it by that column would take more time since indexes are not applied in the union table.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it.  Pretty easy union, followed by a join on your pre-ordered set.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 't1' as source, pid, cDate from t1
    UNION
    SELECT 't2' as source, pid, cDate from t2
    UNION
    SELECT 't3' as source, pid, cDate from t3
    ORDER BY cDate DESC
)
LEFT JOIN t1 ON (source='t1' AND pid=t1.id)
LEFT JOIN t3 ON (source='t2' AND pid=t2.id)
LEFT JOIN t3 ON (source='t3' AND pid=t3.id)
```

Comment: Note, this does sound exactly like the solution you've described above.  Of course, it isn't an actual 'view' per se, which would need to use a temptable because of the union.  I haven't done an explain on this to see if that would be required, but it shouldn't be too bad. If you have a limited number of queries, you could optimize in the union.  For instance, if you only need 20 entries back, limit each select to 20, then limit the aggregate to 20.

Comment: Your answer is not practically different from my current solution. An issue regarding the join is that mysql does not place the value of shared columns in a single column. For example if you have an `image` column in t1 and t3 it generate two seperate columns for them.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL UNION operator allows you to combine two or more result sets from multiple tables into a single result set. 
Some Rules need to follow for mysql UNION are

1. The number of columns appears in the corresponding SELECT statements
   must be equal.
2. The columns appear in  the corresponding positions of
       each SELECT statement must have the same data type or at least
       convertible data type.

By default, the UNION operator eliminates duplicate rows from the result.

```
(SELECT t1.id,t1.name, t1.Cdate ..... from t1 as t1)
UNION
(SELECT t2.id,t2.name, t2.Cdate ..... from t2 as t2)
UNION
SELECT  t3.id,t3.name, t3.Cdate ..... from t3 as t3)
ORDER BY id,name
```

Make sure all columns name should Alias with same name. Otherwise MySQL uses the names of columns in the first SELECT statement as the labels for the output.

Comment: Thanks, but the answer is a part the process described in the question without any additional.

Answer (score 3):

```
In PHP 
 $x = 20;
$limit = "LIMIT ".$x;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM( SELECT id, name, cDate FROM t1  $limit UNION SELECT id,name,cDate from t2  $limit UNION SELECT id, name, cDate from t3  $limit )ORDER BY cDate DESC $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you save one of the entities, you not only save it in the table itself, but you also create a reference entity in a shared reference table. The rows in that table are automatically ordered in creation date.

You know which data must be collected from each table. If the required data for the display is the same for each different entity, then can you make a simple design of the shared reference table. To get all the information required you just query the last 20 rows of the table. Done. The primary key of the original entity is for instance the second column in the shared reference table.

If the data to show is different, then might the design of the shared reference table become something more difficult, but the principle is the same: store the data in that table at the same time you store each entity in its own table.

In the view on the PHP site, you read every row of the shared reference table and make the appropriate links when reading the information from the row. In the row you will have the value of the primary key and the name of the entity (never the tablename!).

Comment: What is the advantage of using an auxiliary tables when a light view (or subquery) can be used instead? It is less effective and require more developing effort.

Comment: Scalability. If you take a look at the queries, then can you see that it will work good with a limit of 20. But what with a limit of 1.000.000? In each query three tables with a lot of redundant information is collected. Then is all that data ordered after which you throw away 66% of all processed data. With my solution you do not throw away one row of processed data, because it is already ordered the way you want it. The moment it requires extra time is when the data is stored. Each end user has more patience when his information is stored then when it has to be retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

The main difficulty of this questions is the part you might forget : getting all the results from the three tables is an easy thing to do. You SELECT, UNION, ORDER.

But getting the latest 20 sources belonging to the 3 tables is a more difficult thing to do, if you want an efficient way not te retrieve all the results.

Better in this case, is :

- 1st solution : Redesign your table using a flattened "table".
  This table would contain all the fields in the three tables.
- 2nd solution: Redesign your table using an inheritance modelling. The main table will contain the commun fields, and a type field will let you know in which other information resides.
- 3rd solution: If you chose to stay with the current model you have to LIMIT before you UNION.

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
           SELECT id, name, cDate FROM t1 ORDER BY cDate DESC LIMIT 20
         UNION
           SELECT id, name, cDate from t2 ORDER BY cDate DESC LIMIT 20
         UNION
           SELECT id, name, cDate from t3 ORDER BY cDate DESC LIMIT 20
   ) ORDER BY cDate DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: You don't need the ORDER BY in the inside selects, do you? And BTW I did not read in the question that he only wants to get 20 results...

Comment: He doesn't asked but I made the assumption that it fit a common need like showing last events in 3 tables. In such a case, you have to order by and limit inside because you don't want your subrequest to return all the content of each table for performance reason. So, we have a subrequest returning the 60 latest rows of the 3 tables using key tables, and an ultimate limit/order to get the 20 latest without using keys.

Comment: Yes, I need pagination on the front-end. However this is not the concert of the question. (as you used the solution is using `limit` statement as you used.)